How to export everything for just one bash -c "cmd" command?
I'm looking for a simple way to run bash -c 'cmd' from the current bash shell such that all variables and functions defined in the current shell are available in the bash -c 'cmd' sub-process (i.e. as if everything were exported for just this one sub-process).
P.S. Anything that relies on double quotes (e.g bash -c "cmd $parent_var") won't work. Also I wasn't able to get these answers to work either: Bash export variables but only for current command (primarily because it assumes I already have all the appropriate variables/functions in a nice clean text file)

Any reason why you can't ( eval "cmd" ) instead?

Ya unfortunately I've cut out a simple component of a more complex problem.
I'm trying to do something like echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs -n2 bash -c 'parent_function $1 $2 $parent_variable' _. So xargs requires an actual executable to be run, and given the need to use positional args (e.g. $1) I can't use double quotes.

Sounds like an xyproblem for either "how do I run a shell command with lines of stdin as arguments?" or "how do I mix and match quoting types in a shell word?"

I'm sorry if I mislead you, but now you know the nature of the problem.
I don't entirely understand how my question translates to the two questions you mentioned.

The nature of your problem is unclear as written in the question. What are you trying to do seems quite needlessly complex and unreliable with quoting issue that will bite back in a way or another. Please try to clarify what you are trying to solve this way rather than writing a clean shell script with arguments.

Your assertions about what "won't work" are suspect. "$(declare -p varname)", for example, evaluates to code that, when run, defines that variable. $(declare -f funcname)" likewise for functions. Call then with all variables or all functions listed on the command line, and why wouldn't that work? (Yes, naively expanding a single variable isn't workable, but it's not as if that's all one can do).

@LéaGris
I realize it's complex that's why I asked about the simpler problem. There are many reasons I'm not writing a shell script, but essentially I'm trying to write the perfect interactive wrapper for xargs (which uses the input string as dynamically defined 'bash functions', kind of...). Also a script wouldn't loop over input sequence.

@CharlesDuffy Ok let me put it this way. I don't mind concatenating onto the users input string (which is expected to come in with single quotes), using double quotes. But I'm not sure how to do that for the entire shell variable & function scope.

@CharlesDuffy Actually thanks I adapted part of your idea for the solution. In particular bash -c "$(declare -f)"'cmd' worked for exporting the functions and the variables I got exported with @Barmar 's answer.

@CharlesDuffy "$(declare -p)" doesn't work well though because it complains about assigning to read only variables.

Can pass a list of non-RO variables to handle that. If software is well-written it'll be using lowercase names for its own variables, and the special ones are all all-caps, so you can just use compgen to expand to variables with at least one lowercase character in their names and pass that to declare -p.

(See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for the relevant naming convention declaring names with at least one lowercase character "reserved for application use" -- yes, that's the POSIX environment variable spec, but it applies to even non-exported variables since setting a variable with a name that overlaps with a preexisting environment variable overwrites the latter).

"Given the need to use positional args I can't use double quotes" -- you can use different kinds of quotes in different substrings. bash -c "$(declare -f; declare -p $(compgen -v | grep '[[:lower:]]'); "'parent_function "$1" "$2"' -- notice how the $(...)s are in double quotes, but the final call switches to single quotes as the outer context.

You can use this answer in a subshell
(export $(compgen -v); bash -c 'cmd')


Thanks this looks promising!
However I also need to have all the current shell functions exported.

If you move all the function definitions into a file, you could do set -a; source funcs.bash

This is a good idea and I might be able to adapt it to solve my problem...
I'll test it soon.

I adapted your idea a bit and I got this working: (export $(compgen -v); bash -c "$(declare -f);"'cmd'). Thanks for your help!

Feel free to post that as an answer and accept it in place of mine.
